# WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Will the value of "WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION" in (www-->default-->index.html) .wlapp ever changes?

If yes, what's the triggering event? (e.g. changes in .html, .js, .css, .xml, .m or .h file)

I'm using the same source code and same MobileFirst Platform Studio on 3 different MacBooks
1) 1st macbook and 2nd macbook has the same "WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION"
2) 3rd macbook has a different "WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORKLIGHT_NATIVE_VERSION is a checksum value of the native portion of the client SDK.

When installing an update to the Studio plug-in (or CLI), and this new build contains changes to the native layer of the client SDK, then this value will change accordingly in the generated index.html file of the application.

Comment: Got it.... thanks @IdanAdar... We've started the git source code with a different version of MobileFirst SDK...